# Python - saving ARIMA forecast data to file

Tags: python

Hi and thanks in advance,

So I'm trying to write my forecast data to a file from my plot which is using an ARIMA forecast. How would I be able to do so, so that I could access the saved forecast data later?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas
from matplotlib import pyplot

series = pandas.read_csv('Quantity.csv',header=0,parse_dates=[0])
series.columns = ['Date','Quantity']
series.set_index(['Date'],inplace=True)

model = ARIMA(series['Quantity'].astype(float), order=(2,0,1))

fittedModel = model.fit(disp=0,method='css')

stepsAhead = 10 
forecastArray = fittedModel.forecast(steps=stepsAhead)
for i in range(stepsAhead):
    series.loc[len(series)] = forecastArray[0][i]

series.plot()

pyplot.show()
```

Here is the data I used to plot with if needed:

```
Date    Quantity
2010/01/01  1358
2010/07/02  0
2010/08/03  0
2011/02/04  0
2011/11/05  0
2011/12/06  274
2012/06/07  1074
2012/08/30  2223
2013/04/16  0
2013/03/18  1753
2014/02/22  345
2014/01/27  24
2015/12/15  652
2015/09/28  275
2016/05/04  124
2017/11/07  75
2017/09/22  32
2017/04/04  12
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could use pickle?

Comment: I just looked up pickle, and I see how I can use it. Firstly though, how do I get the forecast data from my plot before I can save it to file?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You _give_ data to make a plot, so you can choose how to store the raw data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
series.to_csv(yourPath +'\Forecasts.csv')
```

That will be convenient for you I guess.